# Javascript forEach to loop n times

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I know forEach is not very performant but I'm trying to use it (just a learning exercise) to loop something a number (n) of times.

I'm trying this, but I can't get it to work:

```
var i = 0;
new Array(10).prototype.foreach.call( function(){ i++; } );
```

Is it possible to use it this way? What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see that `forEach` is not very performant? It's basically just a for-loop under the hood.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ here, asuming the use of a simple forEach: https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/9

Comment: Interesting, in Firefox, `forEach` was faster (by about 1%) than a regular for-loop; in IE, it was 45% slower. Crazy IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, you can think of `forEach` as being defined like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(cb) {
    for( var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++) {
        cb(this[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a basic example, it's not really right XD But it's good enough for the point I'm making. Namely, `this`.

Normally, `this` is the array you're working on. But with the `.call()` call you've made, `this === function(){ i++; }`. A function's `length` is the number of arguments it accepts, which in your case is zero, so the code never runs. Even if it did (eg. `function(x){ i++; }`) the code within the function would not run, because that would have to be the *second* argument to `.call()` (which becomes the first argument of `.forEach()`)

<del>Try this:</del>

```
[].forEach.call(new Array(10), function() {i++;});
```

<del>This gets the `forEach` method, calls it *on* an array of length 10, passing the function as the callback argument.</del>

I was wrong in the above. `new Array(10)` doesn't work the way you'd want it to. You would need some hackery like `Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function () {})` to get an array that `forEach` will work on. You're better off just using `for`.

Comment: wow, that method is insane. You are right, I should better use `for`

Comment: it's actually forEach that doesn't work the way you want. It skips `undefined` elements and `new Array(10)` creates an array with 10 `undefined`s

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use forEach instead of a for loop you can create an empty array of n items.

```
let i = 0;
[...Array(10)].forEach(() => {
    i++
});
```

You can also get the index:

```
[...Array(10)].forEach((_, i) => {
  console.log('index: ', i);
});
```

for is faster than forEach, but forEach is often preferred as you won't get off by n errors, and the speed difference is negligible unless you are dealing with a massive number of iterations. If you are dealing with massive iterations you really shouldn't be doing it with JavaScript anyway.